# Always show wxHtmlWindow vertical scrollbar

Tags: c++, html, wxwidgets, wxhtmlwindow

Is there a way to always show vertical scroll bars for a `wxHTMLWindow`?
The styles only mention of `wxHW_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` and `wxHW_SCROLLBAR_AUTO`.
My HTML has only a table, and looks horrible when the scroll bar disappears leaving a wide gap on the left..
**Another workaround** could be centering the table in the body, so that there's equal gap on both sides.. but `<table align="center">` centers the text within the table, and not the table itself, unlike in other browsers.
So how do i solve this?

Comment: i found another workaround.. using `<div align="center">` and putting the table inside the div. and it works okay.  
but i'd still like it better if there was a permanent scroll bar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not adjust the table to the width of the window?  `<table width=100%>`